# Do I HAVE to declare every activity in a manifest file?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-manifest

I want to create an Activity but not have to declare it in the manifest file. Is this possible? Everywhere I've seen it seems that every activity must be declared in the manifest, yet I notice that some activities, such as the built-in ChooserActivity, is not declared in my manifest file.

Comment: ChooserActivity is declared in another manifest file and made public to your application. What are your goals for not putting it in the manifest that might help me answer your question.

Comment: Xamarin.Android does it automatically by using attributes (it's like annotations in Java). Probably one can create a tool that will do this in Java, too.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Short answer: yes, every Activity in your application must be declared in the manifest. As described in the Android docs, the purpose of the manifest (among other things) is:

> It describes the components of the application — the activities, services, broadcast receivers, and content providers that the
>   application is composed of. It names the classes that implement each
>   of the components and publishes their capabilities (for example, which
>   Intent messages they can handle). These declarations let the Android
>   system know what the components are and under what conditions they can
>   be launched.)

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html#ifs

Therefore any Activity class in your application **must** be defined in your Manifest. The same goes with Intents, Services etc. even if those components aren't accessible from outside of your application.

As for ChooserActivity and any other Activity which you didn't define in code, they will have their own definitions in another Manifest. If for whatever reason you decide to subclass an existing Activity outside of your application, then you will have to define it in your Manifest too.

Comment: From someone new to Android, from a design point, this makes absolutely no sense!  You can't define activities which aren't in the manifest, and you can't have manifest entries which aren't in your code, so why can't the compiler handle that for you? Leave the manifest for exceptions to the default configuration and have the compiler 'fill in' the rest! Why make us do it?  ...that is unless my understanding is wrong and I'm missing something, in which case, please share so I can learn, because the way it is now, it just seems like tedious and unnecessary paperwork!

Comment: Note, I obviously am referring to Activities which I *define in my app*, not those which are available to use in my app (i.e. the system-provided activities, etc.)  If you have defined the class, you are responsible for adding it to the manifest, and the manifest is only for those activities which you define, not external ones, so again, why can't this be inferred by the compiler for those which don't require explicit configuration?  Heck, add an 'ImplicitActivity' to define the defaults for those which aren't specified.

Comment: There may be some merit to your argument. However consider that 1) They have an existing toolchain and OS versions to support 2) There may be Activities / Services / Broadcast receivers /etc in your project or libraries which you import which you don't want the application to launch / make use of (eg a base Activity, or AppCompatActivity) 3) I'm not sure how useful a default configuration for these components would be, as each component is usually customised anyway, either with a title, icon, intent filters, theme, launch mode, meta-data etc. 4) There may well be other arguments or constraints

Comment: I know this is an old answer, and as of 2018, Activity is split between `Activity` and `AppCompatActivity`. Should both types of Activity classes still need to be declared in the manifest, thus making the current correct answer still applicable and valid to this situation?

Comment: @tom_mai78101 `AppCompatActivity` extends `Activity`, thus it still needs to be registered in the manifest for it to be launched

Comment: @TheIT Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 10):

> I want to create an Activity but not have to declare it in the manifest file. Is this possible?

No, sorry.

> I notice that some activities, such as the built-in ChooserActivity, is not declared in my manifest file

That activity is not part of your application. It is part of the core operating system.