# How to add exported label in manifest when there is no activity tag in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android-manifest

in my Manifets.xml file I have no `<activity>` tag and I am trying to add the `exported = true` but I don't know how. Is there a way? Here is my manifest:

```
<manifest
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        package="com.app.travel">

    <application
            android:name="com.app.travel.App"
            android:allowBackup="false"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
            android:theme="@style/TravelAppTheme"
            tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning"/>
</manifest>
```

**EDIT:**

The reason I want to add `exported` in my Manifest is because when I try to apload the . aab file in Google Play Console it gives me the following error: "You uploaded an APK or Android App Bundle File that has an activity, an activity alias, a service, or a transmission with a intent filter, but the android: exported property is not configured. This file cannot be installed on Android 12 or later. See: developer.android.com/about/versions/12/behavior-changes-12#exported"

Any help will be appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you need to add `exported=true`? What is the problem that lead you to trying to do this?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice that when I try to upload my application on playstore it says it should has `exported` in manifest.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include that detail. Be sure to include the **exact** error message, too. By summarizing the error, you leave out important details that can help us solve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per https://stackoverflow.com/a/20533294/13373270, every Activity must be registered in your manifest. So your first step is to resolve this error.

See the documentation (https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro) for the minimal content to register in your manifest.

Comment: But it works perfect when I runb it.